# Convergence almost surely and Borel-Cantelli's Lemma (proof clarification)

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I believe it is easier if I print the proof below:

> [image]

Several other papers uses the same argument to bound  $\lvert R_n(x)-E R_n(x) \rvert$ almost surely, so I believe it is correct. It should be clear that the aim of this result is to establish the (uniform) **almost sure convergence** of $R_n(x)$ to its expectation (but here, drop the uniformity part, for the sake of simplicity). It is not clear to me what "$O(a_n)$ almost surely" exactly means, but since the aim is show the rate that the almost surely convergence occurs, I believe that a suitable definition could be
\begin{align}
\lvert R_n(x)-E R_n(x) \rvert=O(a_n) \text{ almost surely}\\
\text{ iff } P(\lim\sup_n\{\lvert R_n(x)-E R_n(x) \rvert\leq Ca_n\})=1,\text{ for some  }C>0
\end{align}
this means that $\lim\sup_n\{\lvert R_n(x)-E R_n(x) \rvert\leq Ca_n\}$ holds $P$-almost everywhere. Please, correct me if you have further information.

As far as I understand, he is trying to give a bound from
$\lvert R_n(x)-E R_n(x) \rvert\leq\lvert R_n(x) \rvert +\lvert E R_n(x) \rvert$.

As shown above, $\lvert E R_n(x) \rvert=O(a_n)$, or equivalentely, $\lvert E R_n(x) \rvert\leq C_1 a_n$ for some $C_1>0$ and all large $n$.

Further, he is saying that $\lvert R_n(x) \rvert=0$ almost everywhere (or, with probability one) when $n$ is large enough. **This step is not clear to me**, and I hope you can help me.

**My attempt (Updated)**

I'm on this problem for some days, but not suceeded. I'll try something different now.

I want to show that
\begin{align}
P(\lim\sup_n \{\lvert R_n-ER_n\rvert\leq C a_n\})=1
\end{align}
for some $C>0$ with $a_n\to 0$. Note that
\begin{align}
&w\in\bigg\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i1(\vert Y_i\rvert>\tau_n)>0\bigg\}\\
\implies &\exists i\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}:w\in\{\vert Y_i\rvert>\tau_n\}.
\end{align}
Using this result, the triangle inequality and the fact $\lvert E R_n\rvert=O(a_n)$, for any $n:n>n^*$,
\begin{align}
&P( \lvert R_n-ER_n\rvert>C_1 a_n) \\
\leq &P( \lvert R_n\rvert+C_1a_n>C_1 a_n)\\
=&P( \lvert R_n\rvert>0)\leq P(\lvert Y_i\rvert>\tau_n \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}) 
\end{align}
If $Y_i$ were strictly stationary (he assumed $Y_i$ i.i.d.), then we could put $ P(\lvert Y_i\rvert>\tau_n \text{ for some }i\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}) = P(\lvert Y_n\rvert>\tau_n) $
and so
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty P( \lvert R_n-ER_n\rvert>C_1 a_n)&\leq n^*+\sum_{i=n^*}^\infty P( \lvert R_n-ER_n\rvert>C_1 a_n)\\
&\leq n^* +\sum_{i=n^*}^\infty P( \lvert Y_n\rvert>\tau_n)<\infty
\end{align}
The application of Borel-Cantelli's Lemma gives the result.

Can you give feedbacks about this??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good that you didn't feel confident about the proof because it is not valid.

Comment: Can you point me how could I obtain the result?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Does it makes sense now?

Comment: The first step itself is wrong. $\lim \sup$   is inside the probability and you are treating it as if you have $\lim \sup$ of the probabilities instead of probability of $\lim \sup$. .

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you have any idea to show that $P(\lim\sup_n\{\lvert Y_n\rvert>\tau_n\})=0$ implies  $P(\lim\sup_n\{ R_n=0\})=1$ if $R_n=Y_n I(\lvert Y_n\rvert>\tau_n)$? I think that this result is used there.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Now, I am more confident with the above proof.